# How to send a list type param from angular js to java rest controller

Tags: java, angularjs, html, rest

I want to send list of string from angular js where my controller is coded like

```
 @POST
 @PATH("/postdata")
 @MediaType.Apllication_JSON
 public int postData(@PathParam("datalist") List<String> datalist){
 return 0;
 }

 var myApp=Angular.module('App',[]);
 myApp.controller('myCTRL',function($http,$scope){
 $http({
 method : 'POST',
 hearders : {
'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
'Accept' : 'application/json'
},
param : <new code i want here for the corresponding rest controller>
})
});
```

Note that : List of string will come from one json file , that part i have done by retrieving  a json file using $http and stored in $scope variable.

I want convert this $scope variable into a list and send the list data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a POST request like this:

```
const options = {
    headers: ...
};

const postBody = {
    yourParam: [ 'string', 'string' ]
};

$http.post('url', postBody, options);
```